# Почему первая текстура перекрывает вторую?

Tags: opengl

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>
#include <GL/glaux.h>
#define MAX_NO_TEXTURES 1
#define CUBE_TEXTURE 0
GLuint texture_id[MAX_NO_TEXTURES];
float xrot;
float yrot;
float zrot;
float ratio;
float WinWid=400.0;
float WinHei=400.0;
float Angle=0.0, Scale=1.0;
const float PI =3.141592653; 
const float height = 0; 
double x, y, z; 
float angleX, angleY; 
unsigned int textures[2];
void init()
{
   AUX_RGBImageRec *texture1=auxDIBImageLoadA("Debug/qr.bmp "),
*texture2=auxDIBImageLoadA("Debug/q2.bmp ");
glGenTextures(2,&textures[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,texture1->sizeX,   texture1->sizeY,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture1->data );
glEnable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[1]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,texture2->sizeX,   texture2->sizeY,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,texture2->data );
glEnable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}

void reshape( int w, int h )
{
  if(h == 0)
    h = 1;
  ratio = 1.0f * w / h;
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
  gluPerspective(80,ratio,1,200);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

}
void display( void )
{
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   glLoadIdentity ( );
   glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef ( 0.0, 0.0, -5.0 );
   gluLookAt(x,y+height,z,x-sin(angleX/180*PI),y+height+(tan(angleY/180*PI)),z-cos(angleX/180*PI), 0, 1, 0);

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]); 
   glBegin ( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.5f);
    glEnd();

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[1]); 
   glBegin ( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.5f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.5f);
    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
void Timer(int =0)
{

display();
glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);
}
void Mouse(int ax, int  ay)
{  
angleX = ax-640; 
angleY =  ay;
}
int main ( int argc, char** argv )   
{
 glutInit            ( &argc, argv ); 
 glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA ); 
 glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);
 glutInitWindowSize  ( 500, 500 ); 
 glutCreateWindow    ( "Rus" ); 
 init ();
 glutFullScreen      ( );         
 glutDisplayFunc     ( display ); 
 glutReshapeFunc     ( reshape ); 
 glutIdleFunc  ( display );
 glutTimerFunc(50, Timer, 0);
 glutPassiveMotionFunc(Mouse);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glutMainLoop ();     
 return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя рисовать квады в одних и тех же координатах, может произойти z-конфликт. Нужно сдвинуть чуть-чуть квады по третьей координате.

Comment: убрал лишние квады ,

Comment: Подсказали на другом форуме, всего лишь надо было строчку в коде
добавить - > glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Comment: Я об этом писал в теме http://hashcode.ru/questions/289736/opengl-как-сделать-чтобы-текстуры-были-непрозрачны

Код функции Timer выглядит бредово и непонятно зачем он нужен.